# How to generate dynamic Image tags by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have fetched json through

```
<script>
    function getjs()
    {
        var script =document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        script.setAttribute("src","http://localhost:8080/vigs/f4json?user=3&callback=gr");
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
    var i=0;
    function gr(data)
    {
        for(i=0;i<data.size;i++)
        {
            document.getElementById('w').innerHTML =data.itemr[i].itmurl;
        }
    }
</script>
```

so, after fetching the urls it simply displays url of images in my div. I just confused how to write up code in jquery for same above task but also display images (by generating dynamix image tag appended to next one by one based on size in div) in my div with id mydiv.Or any alternative ?

your help would be appreciated..
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JavaScript

```
function gr(data)
{
  var w = document.getElementById('w');
  for(i=0;i<data.itemr.length;i++)
  {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = data.itemr[i].itmurl;
      w.appendChild(img);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The `.appendChild` method doesn't accept a string argument.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll give you a +1 if you take `document.getElementById('w')` out of the loop, and cache it instead.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But since it is an id won't be much of a problem.

Comment: If `w` is null that means there is no element on the page with id `w`.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, my mistake..after correcting..it dispalays only last image others are not displayed..

Answer (score 2):

```
$("<img>").attr("src", data.itemr[i].itmurl).appendTo($("#w"));
```

Comment: No problem, by the way this is using jQuery so I'm not sure why you asked if that was possible using jQuery in response to the plain Javascript answer.

Comment: sorry,in hurry i didnt scroll my screen,but its great....it helps me a lot..Thanks